# Merging pull request causes foxtrot merge

Tags: git, bitbucket

My bitbucket server has control freak enabled and it's giving me a foxtrot error when doing the following:

- From branch MAIN branch I create a FEATURE branch.
- I do my work on FEATURE branch and push it to the Bitbucket server.
- In Bitbucket I create a Pull Request that is later on merged into MAIN
- I pull MAIN and merge back all changes to my FEATURE branch.
- I push FEATURE branch to Bitbucket server. Control freak rejects PR commit as it contains a foxtrot merge.

I use the same steps on another project from the same server and everything is alright. What's happening here?

Comment: At what point is the PR rejected? Is a merge type selected yet? In your described scenario if you were to do a fast-forward merge of `feature` into `main` it would be a foxtrot merge, but if you did a regular merge it would not.

Comment: Side note, it's not clear if "FEATURE" in bullets 2 and 4 are different feature branches or not. If they are different I'd recommend using `feature1` and `feature2` for clarity. If they are the same branch, what's the point of the second PR?

Comment: I just realized my first comment may not be relevant, because it sounds like the **push** was rejected instead of a PR. I find that odd because if you use a regular merge into `main`, you can't have a foxtrot merge, so blocking the push seems kind of too restrictive, IMHO. (Perhaps instead it should only block the push directly to `main`, or block a merge into `main` that would have a foxtrot merge.) Are you possibly pushing `feature` directly to `main`? Or, have you enabled blocking foxtrot pushes on feature branches as well?

Comment: FEATURE and MAIN are just branch names that I used to illustrate the case, so it refers to the same branches all the time.
"Feature" is never pushed to "main" directly, changes are only merged via PR.
I have another project in the same bitbucket server and these steps show no error. Could it be that the error comes from previous commits that were manually merged?

Comment: I'm guessing you have Control Freak configured to block pushes on all feature branches, rather than just on `main` (and other shared branches). Do you know if Control Freak can block the completion of a PR, or does it only block the push of your feature branch? If it can also block the completion of a PR that would cause a foxtrot merge, then I would change the Control Freak setting to only block merges on `main` (and other shared branches). That way you can continue working and you simply make sure you don't fast-forward when completing a PR. Or, you can rebase your branch onto main instead.